# How to use same random line color for each data pair

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I have two matrix Y1 and Y2 (as two sets of vectors) (they represents some simulation solutions coming from 2 methods)
I want to compare them by plotting :

```
plot(x,Y1,x,Y2)
```

And I want to customize the plot to have connections. I know how to say "first this type, second this type"

```
plot(x,Y1,'o',t,Y2,'-')
```

but the colors don't match. Is there an "automatic" way ? I know I can do

```
plot(t,Y1(1,:),'ro',t,Y1(2,:),'bo',t,Y2(1,:),'r-',t,Y2(2,:),'b-')
```

But it's not the best way...

Comment: How should matlab know which colors have to be the same?

Comment: I don't know, it's why I'm asking

Comment: If you want to properly customize plots, the best approach is always to call them independently for each dataset with `hold on`, as Vahe suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the color order using `ax.ColorOrderIndex`.
For example

```
plot(t,Y1,'o');
hold on;
ax = gca;
ax.ColorOrderIndex = 1;
plot(t,Y2,'-');
hold off;
```

Comment: And with this method, I can add as many matrix that I want. Am I right ?

Comment: sure, just reset the `colorOrderIndex` after each plot. Use the `hold off;` only after you are done plotting. You do not need to repeat the `ax = gca` line.